# <input type="search"> not styling

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I am trying to create a simple search bar with a search icon next to it. But I have noticed I can't style a input with the type search. I tried it on safari (Version 9.0.3 (11601.4.4)) and then on chrome (version 49.0.2623.110). At first I thought it was because the input was not valid but found out it was fine to have the type search.

The only thing I was able to style was background-color and it only worked in chrome.

I also tried deleting all my css styles and only styling the input. It did not help.

I tried googling it with no success.

So is their a way around it or will I have to put my input type on text so I can style it?

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        input {
            padding: 10px; /* Does not work */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</body>
</html>
```

this code does not work in Safari and Chrome on OS X

EDIT: I am using OS X so could it be a problem with webkit?

Comment: Show us your code of your HTML and CSS and what you've tried so far.

Comment: There are ways you can make the input appear as though it's been styled, like how the search box at the top of StackOverflow is.  But please post an example of your code.

Comment: Can't answer without your html and css.

Comment: @AuditeMarlow Sorry for waiting... I did add a code and also found a solution... I don't know if it is the best one. Please tell me if you have a nicer solution :P thanks for the help.

Comment: @SamuelKodytek there aren't a nicer solution, that's the correct solution. However, I post the same solution as you in the same moment that you post. You beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: Where does one find out about changes like this? Previously I know that you didn't need this appearance property to override the preset. Is this a change is CSS or browser styling?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `appearance` property to avoid propietary stylizing and then you are able to style it:

```
input[type=search]{
   -moz-appearance: none;/* older firefox */
   -webkit-appearance: none; /* safari, chrome, edge and ie mobile */
   appearance: none; /* rest */
}
```

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance
- https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

Answer (score 7):

Ok so on the end I found a github forum: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/396

Were they written that its a bug in Safari and I should add this piece of code to my styles:

```
input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}
```

and it fixed it!

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds! LOL

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. My upvote to your answer :)